# Moving code to master page SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium & LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to remove the view state using the method below. My problem is I don't like it put the code below into almost every page. I like to move it to the masterpage or convert it to a class and run it from the masterpage.
The code below on works on the non-masterpage .
It will have this problem if I put inside the masterpage CS0115: 'MasterPage.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object)': no suitable method found to override

```
#region Disable ViewState
protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object state)
{
}
protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
{
    return null;
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //using the below you will need to change  asp:ImageButton coding method. You need to convert it to a regular submit button. There may be other problems which i don't now yet.
```

Place the code below on the master page.

```
     protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {///Articles/How-to-disable-or-remove-ViewState-Hidden-Field-in-ASP.Net-Page.aspx
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter ht = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.Render(ht);
        string html = sb.ToString();
        //The remove the value and it id from the view status this next line
        html = Regex.Replace(html, "<input[^>]*id=\"(__VIEWSTATE)\"[^>]*>", "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"\"/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //To completely remove the view state use the line below
       // html = Regex.Replace(html, "<input[^>]*id=\"(__VIEWSTATE)\"[^>]*>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        writer.Write(html);
        sb = null; html = null; ht.Dispose(); sw.Dispose();
    }
```

Use this technique to detect the clicked button on your aspx page(not the master page). Place this code in the code behind
     if (Request.Form["nonPostBackButton1.y"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write("
**nonPostBackButton1 is just pressed**");
            }

```
        if (Request.Form["nonPostBackButton2.y"] != null)
        {
            Response.Write("<br/><b>nonPostBackButton2 is just pressed</b>");
        }
```

This is the sample of the image submit buttons

```
<input type="image" alt="nonPostBackButton1"  name="nonPostBackButton1"/>&nbsp; Use this method instead of the postback buttons. This is the image submit button 1</p>
<p><input type="image" alt="nonPostBackButton2"  name="nonPostBackButton2"/>&nbsp; Use this method instead of the postback buttons. This is the image submit button 1</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put this in a base class and have each of your pages that you don't want viewstate on inherit from it

```
//a basepage that overrides the methods
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object state)
  {
  }
  protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
  {
      return null;
  }
}

//your page class that inherits your base page
public class Page1 : BasePage
{
}
```

Comment: this is the same problem as i mention on my question.

Comment: no, it uses inheritance so the code is not repeated. You simply have the pages you don't want viewstate on inherit from the BasePage class

Answer (score 1):

```
<% EnableViewState="false" %>
```

you can make this `EnableViewState="false"` on top of every page, which will disable view state on that particular page, but if you want any control to have the view state enabled  than you can enable it by the same `EnableViewState="true"` on that control.

Answer (score 0):

Each page has an option to not use ViewState.

```
<asp:Page EnableViewState="True|False" />
```